# Hosting Shopify Checkout Page on Headless domain

Tags: next.js, shopify, headless

I am developing a headless shopify storefront using Nextjs and React and deployed it on my domain which looks like `mydomain.com`.

How can I have the shopify checkout page, which is normally located on a domain like this: `https://[myshopname].myshopify.com/checkouts/co/cea1049618487c3db729fb11fdc62e89`, on my domain (e.g. `checkout.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com/checkout`)?

Do I need to change something in the shopify settings? Could anyone please give me guidance? I would much appreciate it, as I am currently really lost.

I tried implementing a headless checkout but, as I understand, it is not really possible with the APIs available to me. So I want to use the default shopify checkout page, but on my domain or subdomain.